# Redirecting old dynamic links to SEO friendly links

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, sites

My links are like "http://www.shinylook.ro/product.php?id=58" and I rewrite them like

```
"http://www.shinylook.ro/produs/58/saboti-dama/"
```

using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^produs/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But I cannot manage to redirect the old links to the new ones. If someone will type the old, to be redirected to the new ones.

I tried this one:

```
RewriteRule ^product.php?id=$1 produs/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/  [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I fix this problem?

EDIT:

I managed to write the PHP code... You can try it at `www.shinylook.ro/redirect_old_links.php?id=44`.

But I can`t manage to solve the htaccess rewrite code to redirect to that file...

I used `RewriteRule ^product.php?id=([0-9]+) redirect_old_links.php?id=$1 [R=301,NC]`

But it doesn't work.

EDIT 2:

I managed to solve the problem... the htaccess looks like

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=200

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$

RewriteRule ^product.php$ /redirect_old_links.php/ [L]
RewriteRule ^produs/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And the PHP code looks like:

```
<?
    include "_storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $produs = $_GET['id'];

        $sql =  mysql_query("SELECT nume_produs FROM products WHERE id='$produs'"); // Chose the product

        // ------- We check if it exists ---------
        $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // Count

        if ($existCount == 1) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $nume_brut = $row["nume_produs"];
                $nume = explode(" ", $nume_brut);
            }
            $nume_final = strtolower($nume[0]."-".$nume[1]);
            $name = urlencode($nume_final);
            header("location: http://www.shinylook.ro/produs/$produs/$name/", TRUE, 301);
        }
        else {
            echo ("This product id does not exist!");
            exit();
        }
   }
?>
```

If anyone see some mistakes (I'm new to this domain), I will be very glad to hear them and learn how to do this things better...

Comment: just make sure to escape the input variables you use in SQL queries. In this case, since you want an integer, just make `$produs = intval($_GET["id"]);`.

Comment: i just modified to $produs = intval($_GET["id"]); but can you tell me more about escape variables .. i`m new to php and i dont`t know very much...

Comment: Basically, any time you use user input to add it to a SQL query, you must properly sanitize it. As a very easy solution, you could use `mysql_real_escape_string` in PHP. You want to do this so that malicious users cannot inject extra SQL code in your queries.

Comment: Gah, I can't format stuff properly in this comments section, but just look at this page, at section 2. Technical implementaitons. You will see an example of what an attacker can do, and what you should do to stop it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to redirect the old links to the new URL so that people use the new links when pasting them on blogs and such.

When using `RewriteRule`s, Apache cannot guess the rest of the name in order to do the other part of the redirection.

It can remove it:
`produs/58/saboti-dama/ -> product.php?id=58`
but where would it get the name again in order to do the reverse?

For this, you should write a `redirect_old_links.php` file, which would just redirect to the new location:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Example:

User visits
`product.php?id=58`

`RewriteRule product.php?id=([0-9]+) redirect_old_links.php?id=$1 [L]`

In `redirect_old_links.php`:

```
mysql_select("SELECT name FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID = ".$_GET["id"]);
// the above line is just so you get the point,
// please create a proper query with PDO and proper escaping

$id = urlencode($product_id);
$name = urlencode($product_name);

header("Location: produs/$id/$name/");
```

Sorry, I haven't used PHP in a really long time, and you have to check the documentation for the functions yourself, I don't remember teh mysql_select/fetch procedure. Urlencode may be wrong as well.

But I hope you get the point.

Comment: I managed to write the php code... you can try it here
http://www.shinylook.ro/redirect_old_links.php?id=44
but i can`t manage to solve the htaccess rewrite code to redirect to that file ..

Comment: @user1483138 I see you just edited your question and you say it works, does it? or do you still need help?

Comment: Now it works, i do not know if google it`s ok with my code :).. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @user1483138 it's OK in terms of SEO, as only old users will hit the old links anyway. If it works, please also accept the answer by clicking the checkmark below the vote buttons. Cheers.